# What's the difference between "harrowing" and "poignant"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

What's the difference between "harrowing" and "poignant"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say it's the difference between being being bitten by hundreds of ants (harrowing) and being stung by a scorpion (poignant).  Compare the etymology of the two words:

> **harrow** (n.) "agricultural implement,
> heavy wooden rake," c.1300, haru, from
> O.E. *hearwa, apparently related to
> O.N. harfr "harrow," and perhaps
> connected with O.H.G. herbist
> "harvest" (see harvest). Also possibly
> from hergian (see harry).
>
> **harrow** (v.) especially in harrowing of Hell in
> Christian theology, from hergian (see
> harry). In the figurative sense of "to
> wound the feelings, distress greatly"
> it is first attested c.1600 in
> Shakespeare. Related: Harrowed;
> harrowing.

So "harrowing" carries connotations of being more long-term, part of an ordeal, or how you might feel after being worked over by a rake (or a swarm of ants).

> **poignant** late 14c., "painful to physical or mental feeling," from O.Fr. poignant (13c.), prp. of poindre "to prick, sting," from L. pungere "to prick" (see pungent). Related: Poignance; poignancy.

And "poignant" is sharper, more acute, possibly deeper.  It's the feeling of sudden loss or unexpected injury (like a scorpion sting).

Comment: Thank You, Klay!!! I think You really hit the mark here.

Comment: "Poignant" is rarely used in the sense of "painful" nowadays.

Answer (score 16):

Odd question as these words are not often synonymous.

Briefly, *harrowing* means very distressing while *poignant* means emotionally moving or powerful. Poignancy is not necessarily negative.

Comment: Thank You, PyroTyger. Can You, please, give me an example, in which "poignancy" would be in positive sense.

Comment: I would be happy to, but I think @crypto has done an excellent job! You'll see from his examples that the word seldom has a *positive* connotation, but is not necessarily negative either. (Its origin is closer to "harrowing" or "painful" but the English meaning has transmuted over time.)

Answer (score 9):

In a nutshell,

"poignant" could be used in place of "harrowing", to indicate distress. However, the former can be used in several other situations, as illustrated below:

**harrowing** could mean:

- causing pain or distress.

> It was after a harrowing journey on
>   foot that we reached the belly of the
>   Amazonian rainforest.

**poignant** could mean:

- incisive

> The journalist's poignant queries left
>   the senator lost for words.

- apt; to the point

> His poignant summary of the poem
>   garnered a huge round of applause.

- emotionally moving; sometimes to the
  point of distress.

> The poignant tale of the girl's
>   suffering moved many to tears.

- pleasurably stimulating

> The sight of his childhood sweetheart
>   brought back poignant memories.