# What is the word for poignant, but with a positive connotation?

Tags: word-choice

*Poignant* denotes touching and significant, but typically with a negative connotation.
Is there a word that means the same, but has a positive connotation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on the misconception that *poignant* has negative connotations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "harrowing" and "poignant"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/whats-the-difference-between-harrowing-and-poignant)

Comment: Have you done a thesaurus search on "poignant"? I'll bet there are other words or phrases that may have a slightly different flavor - such as "heart-felt moment", "touching", "meaningful", etc.

Comment: 'Poignant' is the often painful counterpart of the often pleasurable 'piquant'. 'Connotation' is misused in the question, but the particular misuse is common; the question is also overstating the case with respect to senses of 'poignant', but the same would hold true of a reversal with reference to piquant: "Piguant denotes touching and significant, but is often used to refer to pleasurably stimulating or fascinating sensations or ideas. Is there a word that has that same general sense, but is often used to refer to painfully stimulating or fascinating sensations or ideas (*poignant*)?"

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, *poignant* does have a positive connotation, meaning something that is moving or touching but also slightly painful. One wouldn't describe an event as a 'poignant tribute' if it had a negative connotation.

Comment: Agreed. There is no negative connotation to poignant. Words that have a negative connotation are words like mawkish, blubbery, even sentimental.

Comment: The negativity is in the sadness (cf _heart-rending_) of poignancy, which normally refers to the past; there is always some regret in reviewing the past, and that's part of being poignant. But not necessarily a big part, I agree.

Comment: @FeliniusRex: Or lugubrious. Don

Answer (score 2):

How about *heart-warming*? Others which spring to mind include

> - tender
> - touching
> - heart-rending
> - evocative
> - soul-stirring
> - pathos (This is a tricky one. A cognate, *pathetic*, has a negative connotation, but the word *pathos* can be neutral or positive in both denotation and connotation. It is one of the three modes of persuasion, according to Aristotle. Its counterpart--and negative-connotation word--would be *bathos*.)

Comment: heart-rending seems a lot more 'negative' than the original.

Comment: @Oldcat: Not sure I agree with you, but then that could be because I've never heard it used in a negative fashion in my limited sphere of experience! To me, the pictures of poor, starving, swollen-bellied children in a TV commercial for a charitable organization are truly heart-rending. Same goes for the Human Society's commercial with pictures of abandoned and abused dogs, with sad music playing in the background. I have to turn the channel. To me: heart rending. Don

Comment: The imagery is that of tearing your heart in half like a piece of cloth - as in rending your garments in anguish. Whereas the imagery from poignant is that of a prick like a thorn, or a sting. The former seems more severe.  If you want to avoid the sting, surely you'd want to avoid being torn in half.

Comment: @Oldcat: Unless I have a split personality! Point taken, by the way. Don